# WatchOS: getting applicationDidBecomeActive notifications

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm making a framework that needs to do stuff when my apple watch is entering background and foreground.

I'm looking for an equivalent of this iOS code for the Apple watch since UIApplication is not present in UIKit anymore :

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterBackground", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

any help would be nice

Comment: Perhaps `NSExtensionHostDidEnterBackgroundNotification`?

Comment: Did you get any result for this?

Answer (score 10):

As of watchOS 7 the following have been added:

```
WKExtension.applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
WKExtension.applicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
WKExtension.applicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification
WKExtension.applicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
WKExtension.applicationWillResignActiveNotification
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/WatchKit/wkextension

Answer (score 3):

Appears that the WatchOS equivalent of

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterBackground", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

is simply

```
let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: "applicationDidEnterBackground", name: "UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification", object: nil)
```

One just need to replace the emum by its string equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Closest you get is `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationWillResignActive`

```
class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate {

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
      // Perform any final initialization of your application.
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.    
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive() {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: but no way I can register these from elsewhere than ExtensionDelegate ? I'm writing a framework

Comment: An application only has one Darwin Notification Center. Watchkit apps are still part of the same application. This means (I have never tested it) you should be able to send notifications from anywhere inside your application (that being a framework or whatever, that doesnt matter since its bundled with the application), and receive anywhere inside the app.

Comment: but does applicationWillResignActive() triggers any kind of notification like applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) does ?

Comment: I don't know, you will have to try